# How to link kernel32.lib and user32.lib using a combination of `nasm` and `alink`?

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, windows-10, nasm

How to link kernel32.lib and user32.lib using a combination of `nasm` and `alink`?

I'm following some tutorials on assembly programming and the guide wants me to execute the following commands:

```
nasm  -fobj hello.asm                                    
alink -oPE hello \lib\kernel32.lib \lib\user32.lib
```

The first command executes as expected, however the second command fails.

To link the .lib files, I've copied them from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib
```

into my current folder.

The error messages I get when executing the second command is:

```
Loading file hello.obj
Loading file Kernel32.lib
2327 symbols
Loaded first linker member
Loading file User32.lib
1385 symbols
Loaded first linker member
matched Externs
matched ComDefs
Unresolved external MessageBoxA
Unresolved external ExitProcess
```

Now, I've two questions:

**1) Where are kernel32.lib and user32.lib located?**

**2) How can I link these library files properly?**

The operating system is Windows 10 (64-bit).

Update:

```
; Coded for NASM                                           ;
; nasm  -fobj hello.asm                                    ;
; alink -oPE hello \lib\kernel32.lib \lib\user32.lib       ;
                                                           ;
extern MessageBoxA              ; APIs used                ;
extern ExitProcess              ; in this file             ;
                                                           ;
[SECTION CODE USE32 CLASS=CODE] ; code section             ;
..start:                        ; for the linker           ;
                                                           ;
    push byte 0                 ; only the buttons 'OK'    ; 
    push dword caption          ; caption of the BOX       ;
    push dword text             ; text in the BOX          ;
    push byte 0                 ; handle of the Box        ;
      call MessageBoxA          ; print BOX on screen      ;
                                                           ;
    push byte 0                 ;                          ;
      call ExitProcess          ; EXIT                     ;
                                                           ;
    caption db "Your first WIN32 programm",0               ;
    text db "HELLO",0                                      ;
                                                           ;
end                             ; for the linker
```

Comment: You are getting the LIB files from the correct folder, but you really should not copy them elsewhere. Just give the linker the path so it can find them. Otherwise, I would guess that your issue here is that ALINK doesn't support generating 64-bit executables. You need to either generate 32-bit object code, or use a different linker.

Comment: you compile/link 32 or 64 bit code ? and how you declare MessageBoxA and ExitProcess in asm file ?

Comment: My intention is to compile/link 32-bit code. I've added the complete sample above.

Answer (score 2):

I haven' found a `kernel.lib` or `user.lib` that can be used by `ALINK`. This may be due to the format of the needed .obj files, While the most Windows .obj's are formatted in COFF `ALINK` wants to be feeded with OMF.

A suitable `WIN32.LIB` is [here](http://alink.sourceforge.net/download.html). It includes `MessageBoxA` but not `ExitProcess`. It's not recommended to terminate a pure Windows program with a simple `RET`.

However, NASM can do the job as well if not better:

```
; Import the needed Win32 API functions.- http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.4.4
IMPORT ExitProcess kernel32.dll
IMPORT MessageBoxA user32.dll

; Still needed to be declared as external
EXTERN ExitProcess, MessageBoxA

[SECTION CODE USE32 CLASS=CODE] ; code section
..start:
    push 0                  ; only the buttons 'OK'
    push dword caption      ; caption of the BOX
    push dword text         ; text in the BOX 
    push 0                  ; handle of the Box
    call [MessageBoxA]      ; print BOX on screen

    push 0
    call [ExitProcess]

    caption db "Your first WIN32 programm",0
    text db "HELLO",0
```

Please note that the functions are decorated with brackets when being called. Furthermore, it's better to place variables in a separate DATA section.

If you plan a huge project with a bunch of IMPORT's from a bunch of .DLL's tahe a look at the [NASMX Project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nasmx/).

Comment: According to OSDev ALINK is supposed to support PECOFF objs, but my guess is that ALINK doesn't support the new short import record format used by Microsoft these days. The `kernel32.lib` and `user32.lib` from MinGW, more specifically w32api, should use the older import record format.